# How to add data into array dynamically and export it client side csv

Tags: javascript, arrays, export-to-csv

How can i get the input data from users in array and export this data in csv file
what is the best way to do it using javascript. The form will contain, name, adress, phone, shoes size, city..
I need to creat a function to my "add" button to keep collection data from user.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Nome</p>
    <input type="text" name="txtname" id="txtname" />
    <p>Endereço</p>
    <input type="text" name="txtend" id="txtend" /><br /><br />
    //How do i do to keep adding data to my spreadsheet using "add" button?
    <button type="button" id="txtins">add</button>
    <button type="button" id="txtcsv">Download</button>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("txtcsv").addEventListener("click", function () {
        var array = [];
        array.push(document.getElementById("txtname").value);
        array.push(document.getElementById("txtend").value);
        var csv = array.join(",");
        console.log(csv);
        var file = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + csv + "\n";
        var encoded_file = encodeURI(file);
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.setAttribute("href", encoded_file);
        link.setAttribute("download", "file.csv");
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add in your JS code and explain where in that code you're having an issue.  Please note:  this site is not a code writing service.  We help people fix problems with their own code.

Comment: What have you tried to do so far? the easiest way would be to have all the records in an array and by the time the user complete all his/her input simply create the csv file there. As mentioned before, could you add some insight into what you have done in javascript?

Comment: Hello! Currently, you have multiple questions in one. Please be more specific

Answer (score 0):

This creates a string variable with the values of the `<input>` elements as csv and encodes that variable and generates a download link. (download from snippet does not work)

```js
document.getElementById("txtcsv").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var array = [];
  array.push(document.getElementById("txtname").value);
  array.push(document.getElementById("txtend").value);
  var csv = array.join(",");
  console.log(csv);
  var file = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + csv + "\n";
  var encoded_file = encodeURI(file);
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.setAttribute("href", encoded_file);
  link.setAttribute("download", "file.csv");
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
});
```

```html
<p>Nome</p>
<input type="text" name="txtname" id="txtname" />
<p>Endereço</p>
<input type="text" name="txtend" id="txtend" /><br /><br />
<button type="button" id="txtcsv">Inscrever</button>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention something. how I loop it, so people continue to add data and populate the spreadsheet. I added a new button <button type="button" id="txtins">Inscrever</button>
    <button type="button" id="txtcsv">Download</button> and just switch de id.

Comment: You can just move the download code into a separate event listener